# Two-way communication between children and parent using signals

Tags: c, linux, signals, ipc

I'm new to Linux and IPCs, so please bear with me.
I'm stuck at a homework problem where I need to create a two-way communication system, which is:

```
1. Parent sends SIGUSR1 to multiple (1 to 10) children
2. Children all respond with SIGUSR2 to parent
3. If all SIGUSR2 signals are collected, parent pauses for 1 second
4. Repeat from [1], until SIGTERM is sent to parent
```

Currently I'm just trying to get this working with just one child, and I need to use Parent.. and ChildHandler functions to handle acquired signals.

I've tried sending initial SIGUSR1 to child and then using ChildHandler to **kill(getppid(), SIGUSR)** to parent, but this is not working as I expected it to. ChildHandler doesn't seem to receive the signal before Parent starts waiting.

**ParentHandler(int signo)** :

```
    if (signo == SIGUSR2)
    {
        printf("P received SIGUSR2\n");

        printf("Waiting for %d sec...\n\n", WAIT_TIME);
        sleep(WAIT_TIME);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Something went wrong in PH...\n\n");
        exit(1);
    }
```

**ChildHandler(int signo)** :

```
    if (signo == SIGUSR1)
        printf("C received SIGUSR1\n");

    kill(getppid(), SIGUSR2); // P <--SIGUSR2--- C

    return;
```

**Main** :

```
    pid_t pid, ppid;
    ppid = getpid();

    // Subscribe parent to SIGTERM
    // signal(SIGTERM, SigTermParentHandler);

    // Parent <--> Child dialogue
    if ((pid = fork()) != 0) // Parent
    {
        printf("P: %d | C: %d\n\n", ppid, pid);

        if (signal(SIGUSR2, ParentHandler) == SIG_ERR)
            printf("SIGUSR2 to parent was interrupted!");

        while (1)
        {
            printf("P ---SIGUSR1--> C\n");
            kill(pid, SIGUSR1); // P ---SIGUSR1--> C
        }
    }
    else // Child
    {
        sleep(WAIT_TIME); // Wait for parent to finish setting up

        if (signal(SIGUSR1, ChildHandler) == SIG_ERR)
            printf("SIGUSR1 to child was interrupted!");
    }
```

I expect output to be appx the following:

```
Parent PID is: 13918
P: 13918 | C: 13919

P ---SIGUSR1--> C
C received SIGUSR1
P <--SIGUSR2--- C
P received SIGUSR2
Waiting for 1 sec...

P ---SIGUSR1--> C
...
```

Comment: If you call `sleep()` in your signal handler, when will the next signal be processed?  Also, you can only call async-signal-safe functions safely from within a Linux signal handler.  See [`man signal-safety`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html).

Comment: As specified, this problem is impossible, as (non-realtime) signals are not "countable" -- there's no difference between one child sending the signal and multiple children sending the signal simultaneously as far as the parent can tell.

Comment: @ChrisDodd [POSIX real-time signals](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html#tag_02_04_02) might work as real-time signals under POSIX are not subject to multiple signals being collapsed/coalesced.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes, but SIGUSR2 is not a realtime signal

Answer (score 0):

I think what happends here is that the child recieves the signal while it is waiting.
Putting "signal(SIGUSR1, ChildHandler)" above the call to sleep should fix it.

Comment: Okay, so I've tried your suggestion, and it did help the Child to receive the signal before the 1 second sleep. Thanks on that! However, now the next issue is that when parent sends the second SIGUSR1 - nothing happens, ChildHandler isn't called again. Any tips on that?

Comment: I managed to get the thing running by adding 
__while(1)
    sleep(1);__ 
loop inside Child's __else__ statement in main function and adding a pause in Parent's if statement like so: 
    __while (1)
    {
        printf("P ---SIGUSR1--> C\n");
        kill(pid, SIGUSR1);

        pause();
    }__
Now two processes are seemingly having a dialogue. Hope that's how it should work.